# extract rows and columns from dictionary of JSON responses consisting of lists of dictionaries in python

Tags: json, python-3.x

sorry for the confusing title.
So im trying to read a butload of JSON responses using grequests with this loop:

```
def GetData():
urlRespDict = {}
for OrderNo in LookupNumbers['id']:
    urls1 = []
    for idno in ParameterList:
        urlTemp = url0_const + OrderNo + url1_const + idno + param1_const
        urls1.append(urlTemp)
    urlRespDict[OrderNo] = grequests.map((grequests.get(u) for u in urls1))
return urlRespDict
```

Which is all fine and dandy, my response is a dictionary of 4 keys with consisting of a lists with sizes 136.
[image: picture of the dict with lists]

When i read one of the responses with (key and index are random):

```
d1 = dict_responses['180378'][0].json()
```

I get a list of dictionaries that has a dictionary inside see picture below.
[image: d1 with dicts]

Basically all i want to get out is the value from the 'values' key where in this case is '137' and
'13,80137' ideally i want to create a df that has columns with the 'key' (in this case the '137') and rows with the values extracted from d1.

I've tried using apply(pd.Series) on the values dict. But it is very time consuming.
like:

```
df2 = [(pd.DataFrame.from_records(n))['values'].apply(pd.Series,dtype="string") for n in df1]
```

just to see the data.

I hope theres another alternative, i am not an experienced coder

I hope i explained it good enough and i hope you can help. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Please look over how to create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue.  Also, please post code/data in text format, not as images.

Comment: share one of the URLs you are using.